# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure - I am deploying .NET Core 3.1 project locally on IIS server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, iis-7

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

I deployed project using .NET Core 3.1 with static website like no it work by when I deployed website with a connection string causing this error.

[image: This is the screenshot of when I deployed static website]

Now after code first migration database attached project, I try to deploy to the same domain - I get this error:

[image]

below is the connection string i am using

Comment: {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
   //"ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=.;Database=Afak_teck_ERP;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-PMD0TF0;UId=sa;Password=123; Database=Afak_teck_ERP;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Comment: Why do you think it's a connection string problem. And by the way net core connection string should start as "Data Source= ;Initial Catalog= ";

Comment: Run a report to rule out common mistakes https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

This error means the target machine you are deploying to doesn't have ANCMV2,so you can't use IIS InProcess hosting, the right behavior is to either install the [dotnet hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) to the target machine or downgrade to the AspNetCoreModule.

You can try to change section in csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
</PropertyGroup>
```